# Country Specific Shopping Cart

Tags: php, arrays, .htaccess, redirect

I am currently building a shopping cart for a client but he wants different versions for different countries, so to that end I created 2 subdomains one called europe.website.com and one called row.website.com

```
On my .htaccess I also have this...
# Make all requests have www in them
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

just so it forces the www. on the site but this should make no difference to the subdomain but however as it has 'https' I get a security risk e.g.

> The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a
>   different website's address.
>
> Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or
>   intercept any data you send to the server.
>
> We recommend that you close this webpage and do not continue to this
>   website.

so thats the first problem as you can see there! The second problem is that it does not redirect to those subdomains and i cannot figure out why! here is a php code block I have used on my index.php on the main website....

```
<?php
$lc = ""; 
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])){
    $lc = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
}
if($lc == array("ab", "ad","ae","af","ag","al","am","ao","aq", "aa", "af", "sq", "am", "ar", "an", "ac", "as", "aw", "ax", "az", "bb", "bd", "bf", "bg", "bh", "bi", "bj", "bm", "bn", "bo", "br", "bs", "bt", "bv", "bw", "by", "bz", "ca", "cc", "cd", "cf", "cg","ci","ck","cl","cm","cn","co","cr","cu","cv","cx","dj","dm","do","dz","ec","ee","eg","eh","er","et","fj","fk","fm","fo","fx","ga","gd","ge","gf","gh","gl","gm","gn","gp","gq","gs","gt","gu","gw","gy","hk","hm","hn","ht","id","il","in","io","iq","ir","is","jm","jo","jp","ke","kg","kh","kl","km","kn","kp","kr","kw","ky","kz","la","lb","lc","lr","ls","ly","ma","md","me","mf","mg","mh","mk","ml","mm","mn","mo","mp","mq","mr","ms","mu","mv","mw","mx","my","mz","na","nc","ne","nf","ng","ni","np","nr","nt","nu","nz","om","pa","pe","pf","pg","ph","pk","pl","pm","pn","pr","ps","pw","py","qa","re","ru","rw","sa","sb","sc","sd","sg","sh","sj","sl","sn","so","sr","ss","st","su","sv","sy","sz","tc","td","tf","tg","th","tj","tk","tm","to","tp","tr","tt","tv","tw","tz","ug","um","us","uy","uz","va","vc","ve","vg","vi","vn","vu","wf","ws","ye","yt","yu","za","zm","zr","zw")){
    header("location: https://row.website.com/index.php");
    exit();
} else if($lc == array("an", "at", "ba", "be", "ch", "cs", "cy","cz", "de", "dk", "es", "eu", "fl", "fr", "fx", "gi", "gr", "hr", "hu", "ie", "it", "li", "lt", "lu", "lv", "mc", "mt", "nl", "no", "pt", "rs","ro", "se", "sl", "sk", "sm", "tn", "ua", "uk", "xk" )){
    header("location:  https://europe.website.com/index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

As I am based in the UK I decided to add "uk" to the array that redirects to my europe subdomain but no such luck and have asked other friends in the states to check out the site and see if it redirects but still no joy as it just stays on the main domain!

anyone got any clues? thanks in advance!

-Phillip Dews

**UPDATE**

Ok all I have changed it all again and I have asked people abroad to check the site but its still not redirecting! here is my code....

```
<?php
$lst ['euro'] = array("be","bs",ECT ECT...);
$lst ['other'] = array("ab","aa","af");
$lc = ""; 
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])){
    $lc = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
}
else $lc = 'en';
if(in_array($lc, $lst['other'])){
    header("location: https://www.WEBSITE.com/row/index.php");
    exit();
}
elseif (in_array($lc, $lst['euro'])) {
    header("location: https://www.WEBSITE.com/europe/index.php");
    exit();
}
else {
    header("location: https://www.WEBDESITE.com/index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

decided to get rid of the subdomains as the ssl does not work on them and just add 2 new directories to it instead!

Once again many thanks in advance all!
-Phillip Dews

Comment: your certificate is issued for the top domain only, it does not include subdomains. you have to get a certificate that includes subdomains...

Comment: I might delete the subdomains then and just put up new directories in the root and see if that works

Comment: +1 to Gumbo for noticing the country codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lcode = explode(";", $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
$lcode = explode(",", $lcode['0']);
$lc = $lcode['0'];
```

But maybe this gives the same result you get...

EDIT:  Just check what language code you get? `echo $lc;`

Also, you need to provide a default language (maybe 'en') if $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] is not set.

EDIT: You also need to redirect to a default domain if the language code is not in either of your two arrays.  For instance, what happens if the code is 'en'?  Why don't you have 'en' in the top array?

UPDATE:  OK, you also have errors in your php logic statements.  Use `in_array()`, like this:

```
<?php
  $lst_euro = array(array("an", "at", ...);
  $lst_other = array(array("ab", "ad", ...);
  $lc = ""; 
  if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])){
    $lc = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
  }
  else $lc = 'en';
  if(in_array($lc, $lst_other)){
      header("location: https://row.website.com/index.php");
      exit();
  } 
  elseif(in_array($lc, $lst_euro)) {
    header("location: https://europe.website.com/index.php");
    exit();
  }
  else {
    header("location: https://row.website.com/index.php");
    exit();
  }
```

?>

Comment: Seems to work better thanks Stefan, looks like i was using country codes instead of language codes