# URL rewrite – virtual language subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a multilanguage site (English and German) with an url structure like this:

English pages

- > http://example.com/index.php / http://example.com/index.php?lang=en_EN
- > http://example.com/about.php / http://example.com/about.php?lang=en_EN
- > http://example.com/contact.php / http://example.com/contact.php?lang=en_EN

German pages

- > http://example.com/index.php?lang=de_DE
- > http://example.com/about.php?lang=de_DE
- > http://example.com/contact.php?lang=de_DE

—

I’d like these urls to be rewritten as following:

English pages:

- > http://example.com/**en**/index.php, …

German pages:

- > http://example.com/**de**/index.php, …

–

What I have so far is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)\.php $2.php?lang=$1
```

But that doesn’t do anything at all …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(en|de)/(.*\.php) $2?lang=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It would be `$2?lang=$1_$1`

Comment: Thank you — but that also doesn’t affect the url structure … I tried it both on localhost (Mamp on OS X) and my online webspace.

Comment: Yes, @hjpotter92 is right, if you really need de_DE, and in this case (de_de...)

Comment: The url structure does not change with htaccess. The final page change... but you should use for test `http://example.com/en/index.php`

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks! Do you also have a clue on what rule is needed to redirect the user from the root to the appropriate subdirectory based on his browser default language?

Comment: Yes, here withe htaccess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606752/multiple-language-website/13606931#13606931

Comment: Or here with php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964043/country-specific-shopping-cart/9964407#9964407